# How can I manually display the delete confirmation for a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I've made a custom editingStyle for my tableView cells. Well really it's the delete functionality, but with a custom icon (the designer does not want the standard red minus icon).

I've figured out how to suppress the standard icon and display the custom one. Now I'm trying to display the delete confirmation button after pressing the custom icon.

Is this possible? Will apple reject my app for this?

Thanks for any help,

Cam

Comment: As an aside, the designer is wrong. Custom icons that duplicate the functionality of well established interface grammars producing nothing but user confusion. I suggest drugging his coffee so that he sleeps through the next design meeting where you can get the icon changed back to the minus sign. In my experience, nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

You could just display your own button by creating your own cell layout (not as easy as what you're looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Apple might reject the app if it causes confusion with standard interface controls defined by the API. Why should they foster dozens, hundreds or even thousands of different ways of performing the exact same task? Pretty soon, each app has its own interface that user have to learn and then remember every time they switch apps. There is no upside for anybody. Interface standardization is a good thing.